# Need to fix header row on long table WITHOUT using a scrollable div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm attempting to use a jQuery solution to provide a fixed header on table.  I know there are plenty of solutions out there, however most either are unreliable or are based on scrollable div.  I am attempting to use a jquery solution which so far has got me the closest to where I want to be however it's still not 100%, the columns in the fixed header are not 100% accurate and have incorrect widths.

In my requirement the table in question will not be first appearing at the top of its page, and will be very long passing by the typical screen height by many factors. So when the user scrolls down the page, causing the table to move upwards, when the top of the table reaches the top of the browser window, then it should cause the headers to remain at the top of the window.

I've setup a JSFiddle to illustrate this in very basic form : http://jsfiddle.net/8VxYD/1/

You can see when you scroll down the page the header does fix but the column widths are slightly out, i'm not sure whether it's the jquery code or whether its CSS which is the cause.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you just need to add 1 extra px to the width of the column headers: http://jsfiddle.net/8VxYD/4/

The only change I made is:
`floatCell.width(cell.width() + 1);`

Comment: Yep that helped there thanks.  I noticed though jsFiddle imports some boiletplate stylesheet which affects it too.  I found the + 1 on my code doesn't work alone, I also had to add border-collapse:collapse;
         border-spacing:0 to the css for 'table'.

Comment: Spoke too soon, try it in firefox with a fixed width class applied to a few of the columns.  Update fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/8VxYD/17/